# Output data not the same as input data

Tags: c++, io

I'm doing some file io and created the test below, but I thought testoutput2.txt would be the same as testinputdata.txt after running it?

testinputdata.txt:

```
some plain
    text
 data with
 a  number
42.0
```

testoutput2.txt (In some editors its on seperate lines, but in others its all on one line)

```
some plain
਍ऀ琀攀砀琀ഀഀ
 data with
਍ 愀  渀甀洀戀攀爀ഀഀ
42.0  

int main()
{
    //Read plain text data
    std::ifstream filein("testinputdata.txt");
    filein.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    std::streampos length = filein.tellg();
    filein.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<char> datain(length);
    filein.read(&datain[0], length);
    filein.close();

    //Write data
    std::ofstream fileoutBinary("testoutput.dat");
    fileoutBinary.write(&datain[0], datain.size());
    fileoutBinary.close();

    //Read file
    std::ifstream filein2("testoutput.dat");
    std::vector<char> datain2;
    filein2.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    length = filein2.tellg();
    filein2.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    datain2.resize(length);
    filein2.read(&datain2[0], datain2.size());
    filein2.close();

    //Write data
    std::ofstream fileout("testoutput2.txt");
    fileout.write(&datain2[0], datain2.size());
    fileout.close();
}
```

Comment: Only on binary files (opened with `std::ios_base::binary`) can you expect that `tellg` gives you the actual number of characters. (Actually I'm not sure that the standard even guarantees *that*, but the point is, for text files there are implementations where it *will* not work in practice).

Comment: It works when I open with std::ios::binary.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine on my side, i have run your program on VC++ 6.0 and checked the output on notepad and MS Word. can you specify name of editor where you are facing problem.

Comment: It works if I use std::ios::binary when I open the files.. I use vs2010 and notepad..

Answer (score 0):

You can't read Unicode text into a `std::vector<char>`. The `char` data type only works with narrow strings, and my guess is that the text file you're reading in (`testinputdata.txt`) is saved with either UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding.

Try using the `wchar_t` type for your characters, instead. It is specifically designed to work with "wide" (or Unicode) characters.

Comment: He's not reading any characters that need `wchar_t`, those characters are appearing in his output.

Answer (score 0):

Thou shalt verify thy input was successful! Although this would sort you out, you should also note that number of bytes in the file has no direct relationship to the number of characters being read: there can be less characters than bytes (think Unicode character using multiple bytes using UTF8 to be encoded) or vice versa (although the latter doesn't happen with any of the Unicode encodings). All you experience is that `read()` couldn't read as many characters as you'd asked it to read but `write()` happily wrote the junk you gave it.